# Resizing all images in a Word document using python

Tags: python, ms-word

I would like to use Python to select all images in a Word document and resize them to have the width of the text (just like you would do in LaTeX). Is that possible, and if yes, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to :

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-images-python-docx-module/
- https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

You can try to do something like this, i'm not sure my script will work tho, you will have to try yourself :

```py
import docx

doc = docx.Document('document.docx')

# not sure tho...
text_width = doc.sections[0].page_width - doc.sections[0].left_margin - doc.sections[0].right_margin


for i, image in enumerate(doc.inline_shapes):
    original_width, original_height = image.width, image.height

    new_height = int(original_height * text_width / original_width)

    image.width = text_width
    image.height = new_height

doc.save('modified_document.docx')
```

Hope it would work..